# Combine several similar MS-Access Databases into 1 SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, import, migrate

I have about 20 access databases, one for each year from 1990-2010.  Each databases has pretty much the same tables, but unique data within those tables.  (There are some unique tables, but they aren't very important.)

I am using SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access, but so far I can only figure out how to migrate one access database to one SQL database.  Is it possible to either:

1. Use SSMA to import each database to my SQL server, while APPENDING rather than overwriting tables that already exist in the target database
2. Use SQL to merge 20 databases (after I've imported each one), appending together any similar tables

Each database has a few hundred tables, so I'm trying to avoid a manual solution.

Thank you!

Comment: It really depends on the data in the columns.  It's very likely you will have to massage the data to get all into a single table from the tables across each Access data base.  IE: If there's no year value in the tables to differentiate the data (assuming necessary), you will have to provide that by hand.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Each table already has a year value, and I'm fairly sure the columns are the same in tables with the same name.  I think simply appending all the data in tables with the same name will get me what I want.  I just don't know an efficient way to do this across ~200 tables in ~20 different databases.

Comment: You'll likely also want to add a field to all the tables to indicate the source database so you can use it as part of a compound PK along with Autonumber values (assuming you're using those as surrogate PKs). This is the only way to avoid collisions and maintain RI between tables.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: The access databases currently have no primary key or autonumber values.  However, each table has a field that uniquely links it to a source database.

Comment: If the tables don't have PKs, then you don't actually have any databases at all! It also means you don't have any referential integrity issues, so it certainly makes it easier to merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew your data structure was identical in each DB, you could potentially do some fancy Dynamic SQL and `sp_msforeachtable` to merge each table, as long as they have the same name in each of the DBs.

I'm thinking something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL Varchar(max)

SET @SQL ='
SELECT *
INTO MergedDb.?
FROM DB1.?
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM DB2.?
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM DB3.?
...'

exec sp_MSforeachtable @SQL
```

This will **NOT** appropriately handle data type conflicts, and if you have any identity values this won't work at all.

Comment: I think that might work.  I'm pretty sure the data types are consistent across databases, so there shouldn't be any problems.  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Thanks I will!  I have the data backed up on another machine, so if I really screw up I can re-import the access databases into SQL.

Comment: I'm having trouble making the script you posted run...  I'm using Microsoft SQL management studio express.  I made a new query, and pasted the names of my merged DB and source DBs into it.  However, the query doesn't seem to be running.  What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to do each database by hand, but you could try using sql server's data import wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Make a proper normalised design of you global db. Then import your 20 MDBs to 20 SQL databases and consolidate by hand or by script, or a combination of both. My guess is that it will be faster by hand.